gdb programming process on Arduino Duo board hanging on 'load'
I am attempting to directly program the chip on an Arduino Due board, using a Black Magic Debug probe and arm-none-eabi-gdb.  Every time I attempt, the process hangs on the command 'load'
I have created a .elf file that works when programmed with the Arduino IDE. I use the commands below (in Powershell) to attempt to program it with GDB.  As can be seen, everything works fine until I attemt 'load'.  Every time I do so, the first time, I get an error saying

Error erasing flash with vFlashErase packet

Then if I attempt 'load' again, the program just hangs indefinitely until I kill it with ctrl-c.
Could anyone offer any insight regarding what the problem may be?
PS C:\arduino_binaries\New folder> arm-none-eabi-gdb .\Blink1.ino.elf
GNU gdb (Arm GNU Toolchain 13.3.Rel1 (Build arm-13.24)) 14.2.90.20240526-git
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.linaro.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from .\Blink1.ino.elf...
(gdb) set mem inaccessible-by-default off
(gdb) tar ext \\.\COM26
`C:\arduino_binaries\New folder\Blink1.ino.elf' has changed; re-reading symbols.
Remote debugging using \\.\COM26
(gdb) mon jtag_scan
Target voltage: 3.3V
Please report Designer   0 and Partno   0 and the probed device
Available Targets:
No. Att Driver
 1      Atmel SAM3X M3
(gdb) att 1
Attaching to program: C:\arduino_binaries\New folder\Blink1.ino.elf, Remote target
0x001003c2 in ?? ()
(gdb) load
Error erasing flash with vFlashErase packet
(gdb) load

(For info, the reason I am attempting to do this is that I will be using a rad hardened version of this chip for a future project. I cannot use the Arduino framework for that job. This is the only dev board I can find with this chip on which to do some preliminary work.)
